# software and updates can't connect internet

Tags: 14.04, networking, apt, update-manager

Yesterday everything was fine and `sudo apt-get update` worked fine but today it's not working it just say cannot connect to different websites.
Then I tried changing the server in software and updates , it couldn't find even a single server to connect.
Browsers work fine also `ping google.com` work fine but `ping6 google.com` doesn't work.
I'm using ubuntu 14.04
Thanks in advance !

---

UPDATE :
Here is my sources.list :

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20190304.5)]/ trusty main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-proposed restricted universe main multiverse
```

Comment: Can you please provide pictures & output of errors that you've encountered and sources.list file. What is your server selection in Software & Updates ?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS is EOL, after EOL many mirrors drop the archives, and the main archive will move to old-releases.  It's also off-topic here.  If you are using Ubuntu 14.04 ESM which is still supported by Canonical, use your Ubuntu Advantage support as it's off-topic here.

Comment: ps:  when this occurs is defined only as 'after EOL'  (end-of-life) so it was expected anytime **after** April 2019 (14.04 or 2014-April + 5 years), and not all mirrors will 'drop' the EOL release at the same time.

Comment: @UgurAkgul Here is an example of errors :
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg                                
  Cannot initiate the connection to extras.ubuntu.com:80 (MY-IP6::29). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP:MY-IP6 80]

Comment: @UgurAkgul In new post Update I provide sources.list info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to software and updates
Select Other Software
uncheck all ppas
click close
click reload

Go to Lite Welcome

Good luck!

Comment: It worked just fine ! Thanks